# Turn off Webcam flash light metro app C#

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro, .net-4.5

Apologize if I'm wrong, I'm developing metro app using C# and XAML for Windows 8,My app has capability to capture a QR Code image, Save it in picture library, decode QR image(I'm using XZing.Net library to decode) and display content encoded in QR image.
Every thing works fine if I **block Webcam flash light with my finger** and capture image, But if Flash light is ON after capturing image XZing.Net cannot able to decode. Is there any way I can turn off flash light using code.Please check my code below

```
try
{
   MediaCapture m_mediaCaptureMgr = new MediaCapture();
   await m_mediaCaptureMgr.InitializeAsync();
  qrCameraElement.Source = m_mediaCaptureMgr;
  await m_mediaCaptureMgr.StartPreviewAsync();
}
catch(Exception)
{
}
```

"qrCameraElement" is instance of CaptureElement

On capture button Click

```
StorageFile m_photoStorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("QRImage.png", CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
ImageEncodingProperties imageProperties = ImageEncodingProperties.CreatePng();
await m_mediaCaptureMgr.ClearEffectsAsync(MediaStreamType.Photo);
await m_mediaCaptureMgr.CapturePhotoToStorageFileAsync(imageProperties, m_photoStorageFile);

StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("QRImage.png");

try
{
       using (IRandomAccessStream photoStream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
{
     WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap = await BitmapFactory.New(1, 1).FromStream(photoStream);
                            writeableBitmap.SetSource(photoStream);
                            var barcodeReader = new BarcodeReader
                            {
                                PossibleFormats = new List<BarcodeFormat> { BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE },
                                TryHarder = true,
                                AutoRotate = true
                            };
                            var result = barcodeReader.Decode(writeableBitmap);
                            if(result != null)
                            {
                                //Do something
                            }
                            else 
                            {
                               //Display message as unable to read QR image
                            }
    }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

I'm getting `result` as null when Webcam Flash is used. Please help me.

Comment: Where abouts do you check `result`? And have you tried putting a `Console.WriteLine(e.Message);` in your catch statement (where `e` is the Exception)?

Comment: Ok Andy, I added code where i check "result", I hope you understand my problem, basically i need to turn off Webcam flash(LED) before capturing image(because I'm getting "result" as null when flash is used).Can you help me with this please..

Comment: I understand you now - I couldn't find any documentation for the `Decode` method but I'm gathering that null is returned if the QR image could not be found, which it wouldn't be if the flash is blurring it. What webcam is it you are using?... The problem is without some serious hacking, it may not be possible to control this feature as it could be used for malicious purposes.

Comment: Have you tried using different camera ?